# images are copied but only one query is executed

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem with inserting in mysql.
This function should transfer image(s) to the images folder and for each image create a new query so if there is 3 images then 3 queries but only first is executed

```
public function insertNews($author, $subject, $content)
{
    if($this->databaseConnection())
    {          

        // * So this is initalizing our database, now all we have to do is create a simple query.

        $unique_id = bin2hex(random_bytes(3));

        $insert_news = $this->db_connection->prepare("INSERT INTO news (author, subject, content, time, uniqueid) VALUES (:author, :subject, :content, NOW(), :id)");
        $insert_news->bindValue(':author', $author, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $insert_news->bindValue(':subject', $subject, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $insert_news->bindValue(':content', $content, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $insert_news->bindValue(':id', $unique_id, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $insert_news->execute();

        // * Checking if any images are waiting to be uploaded

        if(isset($_FILES['images']) && !empty($_FILES['images']['name']))
        {
            $extension = array("jpeg", "jpg", "png", "gif");

            $insert_images = $this->db_connection->prepare("INSERT INTO news_images (news_id, location) VALUES (:id, :location)");

            foreach($_FILES['images']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name)
            {
                $file_name = $_FILES["images"]["name"][$key];
                $file_tmp = $_FILES["images"]["tmp_name"][$key];
                $ext = pathinfo($file_name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

                $tname = bin2hex(random_bytes(10));
                $temp = explode(".", $_FILES['images']['name']);
                $newfilename = $tname . '_news.' . $ext;

                $location = "images/".$newfilename;

                if(in_array($ext, $extension))
                {

                    if(!file_exists($location))
                    {
                        // * Now we have to upload it to the database

                        $insert_images->bindValue(':id', $unique_id, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                        $insert_images->bindValue(':location', $location, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                        $insert_images->execute();

                        // * moving file
                        move_uploaded_file($file_tmp = $_FILES["images"]["tmp_name"][$key], $location);
                    }
                }
            }
        }      

        header('Location: news.php');
        exit();  
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you get any errors? If not, try to turn on error reporting.

Comment: Check the schema of the table `news_images` and make sure you don't have a unique constraint on the column  `news_id`. Also, why are you preparing `$insert_images` again for each image, instead of once before the loop?

Comment: You create new file names based only on time. Your images might be stored so quickly some of them get the same name. Why create variable `$location`, use it once, but not a second time?

Comment: check your both if condtions `if(in_array($ext, $extension))
                {

                    if(!file_exists("images/".$newfilename))
                    {` become true or not for each image

Comment: $unique_id should be changed in every loop.but i think you haven't done that

Comment: No it should not. unique_id is used to connect news and images.

Comment: If you fixed it, why not tell us what the problem was?

Comment: the problem was with file names. Because of the time they were all named the same. So what i did is in the loop instead of microtime i used random_bytes to create a new name for images so they wouldn't be named the same once again. And also there was a problem with a function unique_id, i don't know why but even when you create multiple posts it doesn't change its always the same id.

Comment: Ah, ok. Adding ramdom_bytes will almost always work, but it still is not 100% reliable. Why not use a file counter (`$key`?), and combine that with the `news_id`, that way you are certain the name is unique, and the name is more informative.